# Pasting from host into vmware guest change characters

Tags: vmware, paste

When I paste text from windows (host) into the vmware's linux shell (guest) some characters are substituted by others; for example:
slash (/) is rendered with dash (-).
Windows and linux (ubuntu server 16.04) use both the same language and keyboard layout.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```